# Initializing a WebView created using SceneBuilder

Tags: java, webview, javafx, javafx-8

I am just getting started with JavaFX and have created a simple gui in SceneBuilder and can get most function to work apart from WebView.

In my FXML code I have:

```
<WebView id="webComponent" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
```

Then in my controller class I have the following code that is run when a button is pressed:

```
webComponent.getEngine().load("http://google.com/");
```

When I try to run the program when I press the button, it first prints a string to the console (I programmed it to do this), but then throws a null pointer exception and the WebView remains blank.

Could someone shed some light on this as it has me stumped at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: You need to change `id` to `fx:id`.

Comment: Perfect, if you want to post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with FXML files, and you want to use your @FXML annotated components in the `Controller` class, you need to provide an id with `fx:id`.

In your case:

```
<WebView fx:id="webComponent" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
```

Usually, `id` is for CSS settings.

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/).